# Android Device Monitor unable to start

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ddms, android-device-monitor

I can't start the Android Device Monitor neither from Android nor manually.
I got following log file:

http://pastebin.com/6MS0tcVZ

At the end it says "java.io.IOException: The folder "C:\Users\MY_USERNAME.android\monitor-workspace.metadata" is read-only."

I couldn't find the monitor-workspace folder. (Show hidden folders is enabled)

Please give me a solution, so I can start my ADM.

Comment: try to run android studio as administrator..